# Pumping Lemma works on language, but language is not regular

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

So i am given this language:

L = { $c^ma^nb^n $ | $m≥ 1 $ and $n≥ 0$ } U { $a^mb^n$ | $m,n≥ 0$ }

And i have to prove that the pumping lemma property works on **L**.
Although pumping lemma can work, i then have to prove that L is **not** a Regular language.

Can anyone help me into proving this thing? And how is it possible that L would not be regular, but pumping lemma property worked?

Comment: The pumping lemma *cannot* be used to prove that a language is regular.  It can _only_ be used to prove that a language is _not_ regular.  This is because the pumping lemma has the form: “Every regular language has the following property….”  The way you use it is that you show that some language does not have the necessary property; that proves that the language is not regular.

Comment: I have edited the question, maybe now you get what i am trying to say. I'm quite new to these stuff and that's why I'm struggling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to show that $L$ is not regular is probably to use the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem), i.e. we have to show that the equivalence relation
$$w \sim w' \text{ iff for all } x \in \Sigma^\ast, wx \in L \Leftrightarrow w'x \in L$$
has infinitely many equivalence classes.

Towards this, consider the words of the form $w_n = ca^n$.
Now for $n \neq m$ we have that $w_nb^n \in L$ but $w_m b^n$ is not, so in particular we have $w_n \not\sim w_m$, i.e. all equivalence classes associated to the $w_n$ are pairwise distinct for all $n$, and hence the language is not regular as the Nerode relation has infinite index.

Another way would be to assume that $L$ is regular and showing that any DFA $\mathcal A$ for $L$ could be modified to be a DFA $\mathcal A'$ for the language
$$ L' = \{c a^n b^n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$$
which is non-regular, which is (probably) provable using the Pumping lemma.
This is a contradiction and hence $L$ cannot be regular.

Comment: another way to see the second claim without going through DFAs is to use that $\{c a^n b^m \mid n,m\geq 0\}$ is regular and using the closure properties of $\mathsf{REG}$